How do I tell if a relationship is becoming too toxic and how do I counteract this?
A key relationship I'm developing is a father-daughter like bond between my 17 year old protagonist (Nefeli) and my early-forties side protagonist (Cadoc). A common theme I expand on is that Nefeli often puts her trust in people who have proven themselves to be untrustworthy. Initially, this is the case for Cadoc as she trusts him (slightly reservedly) but he betrays and abandons her (before their bond develops). However, his character arc leads him to become more of a father figure to her who is more trustworthy. Towards the end of the story, he slips back into his old ways and betrays her once again . . . and it's got me thinking that maybe their relationship is actually toxic. 
I don't know the line between 'a relationship where 2 people are communicating and figuring things out together' and a toxic one. How do I tell if I've created a toxic father-daughter relationship and if I do, how can I fix it and what can I add/take away to make it healthier?

Are you sure you need writing advice and not relationship advice?

IMHO there are some quite toxic elements to the father-daughter relationship in Pride and Prejudice (Dad ends the book considering his youngest's cad son-in-law his "favorite", despite his other SOL saving his family.) I'm not sure why you feel this is a boolean relation, and why if it trips into "toxic" territory, you don't want to depict it. That happens, and I suspect a lot of people can relate to it.

Most people aren't perfect and disappoint each other every now and then. A "toxic" relationship is one where one partner constantly belittles, sabotages, controls, dominates, neglects, manipulates etc. the other.
So, if your father figure betrays and abandons your daughter figure twice but they have a healthy, beneficial relationship in between, that is not a "toxic" relationship. It may nevertheless not be a good one, depending on how massive the betrayal and how deep the resulting hurt.
In fiction, unlike in real life (where you might want to disentangle yourself from someone who proves fundamentally untrustworthy), the most important question is always:

How does that behavior serve your story?

Is it a learning experience for your protagonist in her quest to form more healthy relationships and does it help her to understand who is good for her and who isn't? Or is it a further step towards depression in a dark and hopeless tale?
As you describe it in your question, this seems to be a story where at least this one throughline has an upside down U shape in this part of the narrative. Whether it is a "loser's tale", a "quest", or a "tragedy" (see the second set of graphs in this answer), depends on what came before it and what comes after, and if it ends on this depressing note.
If the downward turn that comes with the second betrayal doesn't fit the story you want to tell, you need to rectify it. Delete it completely, or make it less severe and append a positive turn afterwards (e.g. he understands the mistake he is about to make and avoids it, or he makes the mistake and makes amends; see graph no. 5 in the first image in the linked answer).
Ask yourself:
What will my readers expect after they have read so far, and will this turn of events satisfy or disappoint their expectations?

Also ask yourself if this is a book that you would enjoy reading yourself.
Many aspiring writers write stories that are fun to write (because the writing requires no effort) but not fun to read. They fail to take control of their stories and shape them. Writing is a craft and you have customers that you want to satisfy so they return and buy another book. Even if the main customer is primarily reader-you.
